# new Array(n) creates empty arrays; [...new Array(n)] creates undefined arrays. Why?

Tags: javascript

new Array(n) generates an array of empty numbers. e.g. `new Array(5)` generates `[empty × 5]`

`[...new Array(n)]` generates an array of undefined numbers. e.g. `[...new Array(5)]` generates `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Which part of the process converts empty values in undefined values?

Comment: what's your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread Operator creates a **new array of same length**, copying all elements from source array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
   destination[i] = source[i] // Which is evaluated to `undefined`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

One interesting thing to do here is to check what transpilers will do:

- [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=NoOjDsFMHcAIEEBOiCGBPAFOAlAXSA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.0&externalPlugins=)
- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1#code/NoOjDsFMHcAIEEBOiCGBPAFOAlAXSA)

Both Babel and TypeScript transpile to the same loop iterating over source array, so passing through each `undefined` value.